# Spring @ConfigurationProperties resolver ignores externalized properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use `@ImportResource({"classpath:property-sources.xml"})` annotation to externalize path to some configuration files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <util:properties id="externalProperties"
                     ignore-resource-not-found="true"
                     location="file:${dir.data}/foo.properties"
    />

    <context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" properties-ref="externalProperties"/>
</beans>
```

So, in application I can inject any property from `foo.properties` using `@Value`. Pretty common, yes.

However, when I'm trying to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to do do the same thing, Spring Boot completely ignores any property winthin that file. At first I've thought that something wrong with configuration, but if I put exactly the same property into `application.yml` it works. Compare:

**foo.properties** (ignored by `@ConfigurationProperties` resolver)

```
descriptions.foo.bar.baz = test
```

**application.yml** (successfully processed by `@ConfigurationProperties` resolver)

```
descriptions:
  foo:
    bar:
      baz: test
```

There should be no difference. Also, there is nothing special in the bean itself:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "descriptions", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class Descriptions {

    private Map<String, String> foo = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Map<String, String> foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Why `@Value` does always work and `@ConfigurationProperties` only works for `application.yml` ?

Comment: Did you try using @SpringBootApplication and @PropertySource( value = "file:/pathtofile") annotation

Comment: The `@ConfigurationProperties` are resolved not through the use of the `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` so your attempt in XML won't help. Add an `@PropertySource("file:${dir.data}/foo.properties")` to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation class to have them loaded and used for `@ConfigurationProperties` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum you're right, please add your comment as answer and I'll accept it. PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer also doesn't put loaded props into Environment. I suppose it's what `@ConfigurationProperties` uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML file you are loading a properties file into a `Properties` object, which then is passed to an additionally configured `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer`. That is what all that namespace magic does.

The `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` will use the properties to resolve value expressions in `@Value` or xml. It will NOT add the loaded properties to the `Environment`. The `Environment` is what is being used by the `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` in Spring Boot. This also runs very early in the process.

Instead what you should do is either put an `@PropertySource` on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation class:

```
@PropertySource(value="file:${dir.data}/foo.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
```

Or specify which additional configuration files to load using the `spring.config.additional-location` property.

```
--spring.config.additional-location=file:${dir.data}/foo.properties
```

With the latter you don't need to change anything, just specify which files to load at startup.

Answer (score 0):

[PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation can be used to achieve the same.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class TestProperties {

    @Value("${descriptions.foo.bar.baz}")
    private String descriptions;

    //getters and setters

}
```

ConfigurationProperties equivalent

```
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties
    public class TestProperties {

        private String descriptions;

        //getters and setters

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class someclassname{
 @Value("${file.name}")
 private String fileName;

            FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fip);
//read your file contents
}
```

The value of the file.name can be set in a properties file:

```
file.name=yourpath
```

Answer (score 0):

File *foo.properties* gives a `Properties` object which holds string=>string mapping *"descriptions.foo.bar.baz" => "test"*. The string *"descriptions.foo.bar.baz"* in general can not be converted to structure like nested `Map<String,Object>`s.

On the other side, *application.yml* gives exactly the same structure as the application expects, nested `Map<String,Object>`s. So it works because of this, **and** because of type-erasure: at runtime jvm only knows that `void setFoo(Map foo)` expects a `Map`. So the application is going to throw a ClassCastException as soon as `foo.get("bar")` is used as String, because actual value would be a Map.